# Euclid algorithm less than O$(h)$ division steps

Tags: elementary-number-theory

In the following wikipedia article in the section for the number of steps it is concluded that the number of steps will always be less than O$(h)$ division steps where $h$ is number of digits in the lesser number $b$. Suppose the larger number is $a$. How would one write that statement with the formal definition of Big O notation which is $f(x) < Mg(x)$ for all $x > x_0$ for some positive constants $M$ and $x_0$. I suppose $g(x)$ is the number of digits in the lesser number $b$, but what would be $f(x)$?

https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euclidean_algorithm

Comment: $f(x)$ is the number of division steps needed to compute the gcd, of course. One ought to write it as $f(a,b)$, though

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $f(a,b)$ denote the number of iterations taken by the Euclidean algorithm to compute the greatest common divisor of $a$ and $b$. Then the claim is that
$$
f(a,b)=O(\log\min(a,b)),
$$
since (up to lower order factors) the number of digits in a number is the $\log_{10}$ of that number, and changing the base of the logarithm does not affect the $O(\cdot)$ notation since it is equivalent to multiplying by a constant.

One can write this out formally without using the $O(\cdot)$ notation as follows:
$$
\limsup_{a,b\in\mathbb N}\frac{f(a,b)}{\log\min(a,b)}<\infty.
$$
This statement can also be written equivalently as follows: for every $N\in\mathbb N$, there exists an $M\in \mathbb N$ such that for all $a,b>N$ we have that $f(a,b)<M\log\min(a,b)$.